# MIPS Printing Mathematical Equations

Tags: mips

I was just starting off with MIPS and solving a few mathematical problems i had in class using MIPS and i was trying a new concept and couldn't understand how to print answer using the same variables we use for storing values and not take an extra variable just for storing the answers and an example question was (b^2 + ac)/a.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is quite simple and you can easily do this by following my solution.

.text
.globl main
main :
li $t0 , 3 #storing a
li $t1 , 1 #storing b
li $t2 , 4 #storing c
mul $t1 , $t1 , $t1 # b^2
mul $t2 , $t2 , $t0
add $t1 , $t1 , $t2 # b^2 + ac
div $t1 , $t1 , $t0 # (b^2 + ac)/a
end :
li $v0 , 10
syscall

Answer (score 0):

to print any value in a register in any format you want just follow the syscall table in this link [enter link description here](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

for example if you want to print the number 5 you do the following:

```
li  $v0, 1           # code 1 prints integer according to the syscall table
li $a0, 5            # load desired value into argument register $a0
syscall              # execute given value in a0 and format in v0
```

the print value MUST be in a0. you can temporarily save a0 in different register in case you dont want to lose its original value.